# How do I start a dbt run from the dbt-cloud cli?

Tags: dbt, dbt-cloud

I have a dbt project, and the dbt-cloud cli. I have my account ID and my token. I want to do a dbt run.

When I try `dbt-cloud job run ...` it wants a job-id. But it doesn't seem to like the one I get from `dbt-cloud job list`

Do I need to create a job template sort of thing on the cloud version? or create a json file to use with `dbt-cloud job create` ? I haven't figured out how to use `--execute-steps` with the `job create` call...

ETA: AH, I seem to have too many accounts and was running from the wrong one? I think it's working now?

Comment: I think you need to define a job in the UI first, under Deploy > Jobs. Then you can click into the job, and grab the ID from the url. e.g., https://cloud.getdbt.com/next/deploy/54647/projects/87477/jobs/73654, the ID is 73654. I would think that would be the same ID you get from `dbt-cloud job list` though?